# How to set text into Label in UI which is loaded by QUiLoader

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have following situation:

[image]

- Load Ui button is part of central widget layout.
- Central widget have a QWidget on right side of Load Ui button. that widget's main layout
  have two more empty layouts lay1 and lay2
- On clicking Load Ui a Ui form, having a QLable(Print here)and a QPushButton(Load Line Editor), is loaded to lay1 through dynamic ui loader.
- On clicking Load Line Editor will add QLineEdit to lay2

Now I want to take text of line edit and print it to QLabel("Print here")

I am clueless how to do that without making any intermediate variable.

Following is part of mainwindow class definition:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    lay1 =  new QHBoxLayout;
    lay2 =  new QHBoxLayout;
    laymain = new QVBoxLayout;
    laymain->addLayout(lay1);
    laymain->addLayout(lay2);
    ui->widget->setLayout(laymain);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(LoadEdit()));
}

void MainWindow::LoadEdit()
{
 if(lay1->isEmpty())
     {

         QUiLoader load;
         QFile file("E:\\WorkFolder\\Qt\\ValueOfFilter\\PrintValue.ui");
             file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
         QWidget * edit = load.load(&file,this);

         lay1->addWidget(edit,Qt::Horizontal);

         edit->addAction(act);
         QPushButton * textbutton = edit->findChild<QPushButton*>("pushButton");
         connect(textbutton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(LoadEditClicked()));

}

void MainWindow::LoadEditClicked()
{
   if(lay2->isEmpty())
   {
        QLineEdit * lineedit = new QLineEdit;

        lay2->addWidget(lineedit);
   }
        //want to take text from lineedit and print it to label
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved when I made edit as member of mainwindow and then changed LoadEditClicked as :

```
void MainWindow::LoadEditClicked()
 {
     if(lay2->isEmpty())
        {
             QLineEdit * lineedit = new QLineEdit;

             lay2->addWidget(lineedit);


         QLabel * label = edit->findChild<QLabel*>("label");

         connect(lineedit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),label,SLOT(setText(QString)));
    }
 }
```

thanks @lwinhtooko for comment

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
void MainWindow::LoadEditClicked()
{
   if(lay2->isEmpty())
   {
        QLineEdit * lineedit = new QLineEdit;

        lay2->addWidget(lineedit);
   }
   QLabel * label = edit->findChild<QLabel*>("label");
   label->setText(lineedit->text());
}
```

Comment: Since I have loaded Ui dynamically and then to access QLabel i have to write: QLabel * label = edit->findChild<QLabel *>("label"); when i do so it will be local to that slot so i cant access it in another slot.

Comment: Where did you create QLabel? If QLabel is not created, yet when you click textButton, you create QLabel first and then set text from LineEdit to it.

Comment: It is part of Ui form that I loaded dynamically using QUiLoader and set it to lay1 and I have to set text of it through lineedit which is created in another slot and added to lay2

Comment: edit is the ui that you have loaded. so try edit->yourlabelname->setText("text").

Comment: well edit is also local ok let me try this with making edit as member of mainwindow.

Answer (score 0):

There is a signal emitted whenever the text inside the lineedit is changed

```
textChanged( const QString & text )
```

connect this to the `settext()` slot of `QLabel`

```
connect(lineedit , SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),label, SLOT(setText(QString )));
```

Comment: lineedit and label are local for both of slots see definition of slots LoadEdit() and LoadEditClicked()